# if(Expr,Expr) structure in C?

Tags: c

anybodys know what is logical means of if(Expr,Expr) structure in C?
like:

```
if(lcn = (ULONG)GetLCN(index),lcn)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Some tips: (1) You should separate your paragraphs by using at least two line breaks, and (2) You should format code by highlighting the code and clicking the "101010" button at the top of the editing area. (You can also just indent with four spaces) Hope you enjoy your stay here!

Answer (score 9):

When you have the ",", the expression evaluates to the last expression in the list.

So: 1,3 == 3.

This can also be interpreted as this:

```
lcn = (ULONG)GetLCN(index);
if (lcn) { .... }
```

Why they did this, I can't say.

Comment: As an assignment evaluates to the assigned value they may has well have left it as `if (lcn = (ULONG)GetLCN(index))`, some people like an extra set of parentheses to indicate that `=` in and `if` clause is deliberate: `if ( (lcn = (ULONG)GetLCN(index)) )`.

Comment: I sense someone was annoyed by GCC's parenthesis warnings and just added the comma operator in there :)

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in action. When you have

```
if(expr1, expr2)...
```

`expr1` is evaluated and discarded and `expr2`'s value is used in if statement.

Answer (score 2):

`a, b` evaluates first `a`, then `b` and the whole expression has the value of `b`. So e.g. `(false, true)` evaluates to true.

The expression you give as an example has the value of `lcn` after the assignment has been performed. The same thing could be, and more typically is, written `if ((var = func()))` (the extra parentheses suppress compiler warnings guarding against accidental use of `=` instead of `==`).

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing C's [comma operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh.aspx) in action.

Basically, all expressions but the last are evaluated but their results are discarded; then the last is evaluated and returned into the rest of the expression.

So in your case, `lcn` is being set and then checked (in the `if` statement).